# TensorFlow Lite and MAUI .NET

Tags: tensorflow, maui

I want to ask how can I upload "tf lite model" to my MAUI .NET project?
What libraries should I use?! And how do i do that?
If there are any examples I'd like to see it,
Thanks.

I've tried to add the Yolo model to MAUI.NET but it's taking too long to do the process, and I want to use tf lite because it's faster than the onnx models.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.TensorFlow.Lite

If topic still actual